# ТИРЕ в предложениях

Tags: пунктуация

Спасибо большое за подробный ответ, но я не совсем понял следующие моменты:

1. "Отец его - военный доктор..."
   "В приведенном примере тире ставится обязательно, что определяется наличием местоимения "его". Может быть, я что-то неправильно понял в ответе. В правилах написано: "Тире обычно не ставится, если подлежащее выражено местоимением, а сказуемое –  существительным: "Я честный человек...", «Вы студент?», "Я русский". НО: "Я/ОН-гражданин России". Такое предложение пишется с тире в любом стиле?
2. "Но даже при отсутствии местоимения тире нужно поставить в связи с распространенностью сказуемого". В 3 примере: "Человек, которого я видел вчера, - главный врач". "Здесь постановке тире также способствует распространенность подлежащего". Я не совсем понял, что означают "Распространенность сказуемого/подлежащего". Если не трудно, объясните, пожалуйста. И еще 1 вопрос. В каких случаях/кому уместно написать: "Это мой брат/дом/журнал." А когда  нужно ставить тире. Или  "Это - дом" и без тире: "Это библиотека". В разговорной речи понятно, когда нужно выделить интонацией, а в каких случаях это нужно в письменной речи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Отец его (мой) - военный доктор. Здесь не личное, а притяжательное местоимение. Если убрать тире, то получим: "Отец его военный доктор", то есть непонятно, к чему относится"его" - к подлежащему или сказуемому.

2) Если подлежащее выражено личным местоимением, то тире обычно не ставится. В этом случае и без паузы ясно, что местоимение является подлежащим. Но возможно авторское тире: Я - гражданин Советского Союза! В этом случае на "я" падает логическое ударение, а после логического выделения всегда следует пауза, которую мы обозначаем тире. Таким образом, делая паузу, мы  всегда выделяем подлежащее, подчеркиваем его значимость.

3)  Говоря в общем, распространенность подлежащего или сказуемого способствует постановке тире, так как нам важно разделить группы подлежащего и сказуемого.Например: "Озеро, заросшее камышом, –  не лучшее место для купания". Но: "Это озеро не лучшее место для купания".

4) "Это библиотека". Подлежащее выражено указательным местоимением, нет паузы и тире. Но: "Это – двух соловьёв поединок.   Это – древний Сфинкс". В этих предложениях авторское тире,  обозначающее паузу (логическое выделение местоимения).

Comment: Встречала в учебниках требование ставить тире в предложениях типа "Это озеро - не лучшее место для купания", потому что отрицание относится к "лучшее", а не к сказуемому. Ни у Розенталя, ни в ПАСе этого нет, а вот в пособиях для школьников - есть.

Comment: Частица НЕ относится к словосочетанию "лучшее место".